# Paypal Adaptive Payments processing Personal payments

Tags: php, paypal

My application processes payments using the Adaptive Payments Pay API, it is just the API called, it is not a sender or receiver of the funds. The payment's are set as personal payments as they are gifts. Everything works fine in sandbox, the problem is when switching to live, I get API credentials from my business account and set them in my app for the live site, but now I get an error "The caller's credential doesn't have permission for the payment type PERSONAL"

I guess this is because my business account is the API caller, but I don't see how that should stop me from processing personal payments when the receiver is a personal account (as is sender). Anyway around this?

Or do I have to use a personal account to process payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get a live App ID for your application?  When you applied for that app you should have explained that you'll need to be process personal payments so they could enable that feature for you.

You can indeed send personal payments from business accounts, but you just need to get it enabled for your app.

Comment: This is exactly the issue, I actually figured it out myself but forgot to update the question. Thanks.