# Adaptive Payments Pay API Personal Pay Key request

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paykey

I know this question is linked to [Paypal Adaptive Payments processing Personal payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721010/paypal-adaptive-payments-processing-personal-payments)
where I have the same set-up - I have a website that is enabling users to send personal gifts from one personal paypal account to another personal paypal account.  My website, or business account, never is the sender or receiver.  So I'm getting my developers to use the PAY API and they are having problems with integrating this to make it work.  They say there is a request for a Pay Key?  In the answer of the question I copied the above link to it suggests that I will need a Live APP ID?  Do I also need my business credentials even though my account is not involved in the transaction?  PLease help... I'm not technical but my developers won't work on this as they say I need the correct API for this to work.  I know the API is correct, but how to get the Pay Key and credentials?
THank you!!!!

Comment: Any use of the PayPal APIs requires that the API caller (you) be an authenticated user. Many of the APIs also require that the "app" (the reason you are calling PayPal APIs) be registered with PayPal.

Comment: Then, once PayPal knows who you are, you need to address permissions to make the actual payment(s) involved. This last step is what the Pay Keys are about. So overall you need to know what application is being invoked, by what API user, on whose behalf to move funds (both/all parties involved in the money movement). But your question is quite broad (as is this explanation, therefore) and you will probably need to spend some time with the PayPal docs and come back with more specific questions to get more help from the SE community.

Comment: thank you.  I have now received a valid Live App ID for my website.  I spoke to PayPal on the phone as my developers are still asking for a Pay Key but PayPal have advised me that there is no Pay KEY needed. But the code is not working so I'm not sure what to do now.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://redpocketgifts.com/youtubeapi/adp/  (don't pay attention to the name of the folder... it's the PayPal code ;)

Comment: dgFlow = top.dgFlow || top.opener.top.dgFlow;
dgFlow.closeFlow();
top.close();

</script>


<script>
var dgFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: 'submitBtn' });
</script>


<form action="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay"
target="PPDGFrame">
<input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
<input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="AP-5L061768FS5678353">  
<input id="preapprovalkey" type="hidden" name="preapprovalkey" value="PA-05072631H6034030W">  
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal">  </form>